# ML.NET: Recommandation using GUID as ID

Tags: .net, recommendation-engine, ml.net

I have a video telemetries, the userId,the videoId and the type (view or like).
I would like to use ML.NET to have recommandation engine and to recommend X videos to a user.

All the samples use Integer as Id. How to use ML.NET with GUID as Id ?

The data model in DB is:

```
public class Video 
{
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class VideoTelemetry
{
public Guid Id {get;set;}
public DateTime DateTime {get;set;}
public Guid VideoId {get;set;}
public Guid UserId {get;set;}
public VideoTelemetryType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum VideoTelemetryType
{
Like,
Viewed
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?